# Redmail: Python sending email too slow

Tags: python, smtp

I was first using smtplib to send email but then shifted to redmail because it was more concise. (smptlib also took time sending email)

this is how I am doing it

```
from redmail import outlook
outlook.username = 'XXXXXXX'
outlook.password = 'XXXXXX'
def send_email(subject, body, to_email):
    try:
        outlook.send(
            subject=subject,
            receivers=[to_email],
            html=body
        )
        print(f"Email sent successfully to {to_email}")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Email to {to_email} could not be sent. Error: {e}")


try:
    obj = {
    "name": "John",
    "start" : "Hi. Hope you are doing good",
    "end": "Regards"
    }
    for index, recipient in enumerate(data['emails']):
        obj["name"] = data['names'][index]
        subject = 'Report'
        body = generate_html(obj)
        start_time = time.time()
        msg = send_email(subject, body, recipient)

        print(f"Email sent successfully to {recipient}")
        elapsed_time = time.time() - start_time
        print(elapsed_time)
            
except Exception as e:
    print(f"An error occurred: {e}")
```

Right now I ran this for two emails in the array
and this is the time elapsed in seconds I get for both in the loop:

17.251704931259155

19.297873735427856

Why is it so much? I have to loop through many emails. How to make it faster?

Comment: Turn on smtplib debugging smtp (session tracking) https://docs.python.org/3/library/smtplib.html#smtplib.SMTP.set_debuglevel. Report time of longest delays with smtp session stage.

Comment: @AnFi Would it help with `redmail` as well?